# Unable to upload .docx format file downloaded via google drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip

Unable to upload .docx format file (downloaded via google drive) but it's working when .docx file generated via "Microsoft Word".

using MimeType for .docx is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

*note : Using paperclip gem(version: 5.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach an image AND a document you need to create another paperclip attribute for the document. On your model:

```
has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

If you want to attach an image OR a document you can do the following:

```
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

If you choose the first option you will need two file inputs on your view, with the second only one. It's not right or wrong on this. It depends what you want to do.

if you want to upload doc format with google drive please follow this link:
https://github.com/evinsou/paperclip-googledrive

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, 

Problem statement here is slight different. below mentioned MimeType itself didn't work when you download .docx file from google drive & it works if .docx file you create from MS word. 

"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Comment: @Rakesh: have u got the solution for this? I am also facing the same problem